# get input value with ajax

Tags: ajax, forms

I'm trying to get the value of an input with ajax, but i only manage to get the full input, not its value.

Here is my code:

```
$("#formulaire1").submit(function(e){ // On sélectionne le formulaire par son identifiant
    e.preventDefault(); // Le navigateur ne peut pas envoyer le formulaire

    var donnees = $(this).serialize(); // On créer une variable content le formulaire sérialisé

    $.ajax({
        url : 'index.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : donnees,
        success : function(data, statut){

            if (text1 !== '') { $("#resultat").text(text1[0]);}
```

I think I should use .val() but I can't make it work while putting this result in #resultat.

Could you please help me?

thanks you very much!

Comment: text1 is not defined anywhere...

Comment: yes it is in my form. It's hidden because i've serialized data.

Comment: actually if I use "$("#resultat").append(text1[0]);", the whole input box with the value inside the box shows up in #resultat. But what I want is to only return the value itself in #resultat, not the input box.